# Javascript: Accessing Parent Object's property in Child Object Property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have javascript object like following:

```
var endpoints = {
  User: { 
    endpoint: '/api/v1/users/%s',
    subResources: {
      profile: {
       // IN BELOW LINE I WANT TO ACCESS PARENT OBJECT'S Property
       endpoint: endpoints.User.endpoint + '/profile'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this object has a object called 'User' which has property called `endpoint` i want to access this property in it's child object called `subResources.endpoint`.

Comment: You will have to do it after you've initialised the object.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible, as the `endpoints` object itself is not fully formed yet.

So, you can do this in two steps, like this

```
var endpoints = {
  User: {
    endpoint: '/api/v1/users/%s',
    subResources: {}
  }
};

endpoints.User.subResources.profile = {
  endpoint: endpoints.User.endpoint + '/profile'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach would be, to use a method/function:

```
var endpoints = {
    User: {
        endpoint: '/api/v1/users/%s',
        subResources: {
            profile: {
                endpoint: function(){
                   return endpoints.User.endpoint + '/profile';
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```